# Find out what the realm is for a Juniper Connect VPN session?

Tags: vpn, juniper

I'm currently VPN using a web interface through Juniper that asks for username and password. I want to programmatically connect but I have to use `nclauncher.exe`, which requires me to enter a "realm".

How do I find out which realm I'm logging into?

Answer (score 16):

The realm is usually your company name. You can "programmatically" find the realm by getting the value of the hidden realm element in the page you usually login. say for example you are logging into http://yourcompany.com. you will see the user login page. now open the page source in the browser and search for realm. you will find a hidden element. Your relam is the value in the hidden element.

Comment: The realm tag appears on the log-in page, but not from the dashboard. <select size="1" name="realm">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>

Comment: @kelorek, your comment is extremely useful! Thanks! You might consider making it into an answer.

Comment: @kelorek i have mydomain.com and i see some "realm1" and VPN works. But i also have  mydomani.com/ops/ login.. and it has same realm.. can it be? something musst be different..